# Image Loading slowly while gridview scrolls faster

Tags: android, gridview

Am developing a custom gallery with grid view and and i have implemented everything as in the android documentation ,Like implementing memory cache for smooth scrolling, Handiling bitmaps efficiently, Processing Bitmaps off the Ui thread and everything works fine now But except one.. When i was compared my app with android native gallery i found that my app is loading images very slower when am scrolling the gridview fastly..Even if it loaded everything and after i scrolls up and it will load again ..But it's fine if i scrolls in a morderate speed..

can anyone help me in this?

Comment: if its loading again ,it means you caching logic has some problem

Comment: You need to add your code for us to evaluate

Comment: "everything as in the android documentation", do you mean you have implemented `Bitmap recycling` and `Viewholder`?

Comment: @mmlooloo yes implemented viewholder and recycling